# Python pandas: how does chunksize works?

Tags: python, pandas, chunks

I have the following code:

```
from numpy import dtype
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

inputFile='data.json'
chunks = pd.read_json(inputFile, lines=True, chunksize = 1000)
original_stdout = sys.stdout

i = 1

for c in chunks:
    location = c.location.str.split(',')
    for b in range(1000):
        print(location[b])
        if not type(location[b]) == float:
            # get the country name
            country = location[b][-1]
        else:
            country = 'unknown'
```

I'm extracting the location field from a large file including json objects. Because the file is so large, I've divided it into 1000-line chunks. I cycle through each chunk and retrieve the information I require:

```
for c in chunks:
    location = c.a.str.split(',')
    for b in range(1000):
        print(location[b])
```

All goes smoothly during the first iteration. At the second iteration the line:

```
print(location[b])
```

gives the error:

```
ValueError: 0 is not in range
```

How do I cycle trough the chuncks following the first?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is the file actually including only line-delimited json objects? As a side-note, I would read from the reader using a context manager: `with pd.read_json(inputFile, lines=True, chunksize = 1000) as reader:` and then inside the rest of your code

Comment: That's correct the fileis only including line-delimited json objects:

{"location":"united kingdom", ... }
{"location":"italy", ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by doing `location[b]` you are accessing the `location` frame **by index** (i.e., here you are asking for the row with the index value `b`). The chunks will follow the index correctly, which means the first chunk will have the index starting by `0`, the second by `1000`, and so on. This means, index `0` will only be contained in the first chunk.

So, instead, you need to iterate the rows without the index:

```
for row in location:
   # Do something.
```

In fact, probably if you look at the full trace of the error you will also see a `KeyError` below the `ValueError`.

To iterate the Series and have the index you can use [`Series.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
for idx, row in a.iteritems():
   # Do something...
```

Comment: Do you know how to return the row index inside your version of the for loop?

Comment: @Dino please see my edit